# The parent dropdown menu button does not navigate to href location

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, navigation

I have the following code for a drop downmenu on my site but when I click on it nothing happens. How can I get this to follow the href link?

```
<li class="dropdown"> <a href="iaas/index.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">IaaS<span class="caret"></span></a>
```

That is the parent item in the dropdown menu. The child items work fine.

I'm looking at the dropdown-toggle class in the CSS file and for some reason it's all jumbled up and listed on one infinite line. It's difficult to read!

The CSS file is from "http://getbootstrap.com/" and I have Bootstrap v3.0.3.

```
dropdown-toggle.btn-default{color:#333;background-color:#ebebeb;border-color:#adadad}.btn-default:active,.btn-default.active,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-default{background-image:none}.btn-default.disabled,.btn-default[disabled],fieldset[disabled] .btn-default,.btn-default.disabled:hover,.btn-default[disabled]:hover,fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:hover,.btn-default.disabled:focus,.btn-default[disabled]:focus,fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:focus,.btn-default.disabled:active,.btn-default[disabled]:active,fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:active,.btn-default.disabled.active,.btn-default[disabled].active,fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.active{background-color:#fff;border-color:#ccc}.btn-default .badge{color:#fff;background-color:#fff}.btn-primary{color:#fff;background-color:#428bca;border-color:#357ebd}.btn-primary:hover,.btn-primary:focus,.btn-primary:active,.btn-primary.active,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary{color:#fff;background-color:#3276b1;border-color:#285e8e}.btn-primary:active,.btn-primary.active,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary{background-image:none}.btn-primary.disabled,.btn-primary[disabled],fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary,.btn-primary.disabled:hover,.btn-primary[disabled]:hover,fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:hover,.btn-primary.disabled:focus,.btn-primary[disabled]:focus,fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:focus,.btn-primary.disabled:active,.btn-primary[disabled]:active,fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:active,.btn-primary.disabled.active,.btn-primary[disabled].active,fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.active{background-color:#428bca;border-color:#357ebd}.btn-primary .badge{color:#428bca;background-color:#fff}.btn-warning{color:#fff;background-color:#f0ad4e;border-color:#eea236}.btn-warning:hover,.btn-warning:focus,.btn-warning:active,.btn-warning.active,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-warning{color:#fff;background-color:#ed9c28;border-color:#d58512}.btn-warning:active,.btn-warning.active,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-warning{background-image:none}.btn-warning.disabled,.btn-warning[disabled],fieldset[disabled] .btn-warning,.btn-warning.disabled:hover,.btn-warning[disabled]:hover,fieldset[disabled] .btn-warning:hover,.btn-warning.disabled:focus,.btn-warning[disabled]:focus,fieldset[disabled] .btn-warning:focus,.btn-warning.disabled:active,.btn-warning[disabled]:active,fieldset[disabled] .btn-warning:active,.btn-warning.disabled.active,.btn-warning[disabled].active,fieldset[disabled] .btn-warning.active{background-color:#f0ad4e;border-color:#eea236}.btn-warning .badge{color:#f0ad4e;background-color:#fff}.btn-danger{color:#fff;background-color:#d9534f;border-color:#d43f3a}.btn-danger:hover,.btn-danger:focus,.btn-danger:active,.btn-danger.active,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-danger{color:#fff;background-color:#d2322d;border-color:#ac2925}.btn-danger:active,.btn-danger.active,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-danger{background-image:none}.btn-danger.disabled,.btn-danger[disabled],fieldset[disabled] .btn-danger,.btn-danger.disabled:hover,.btn-danger[disabled]:hover,fieldset[disabled] .btn-danger:hover,.btn-danger.disabled:focus,.btn-danger[disabled]:focus,fieldset[disabled] .btn-danger:focus,.btn-danger.disabled:active,.btn-danger[disabled]:active,fieldset[disabled] .btn-danger:active,.btn-danger.disabled.active,.btn-danger[disabled].active,fieldset[disabled] .btn-danger.active{background-color:#d9534f;border-color:#d43f3a}.btn-danger .badge{color:#d9534f;background-color:#fff}.btn-success{color:#fff;background-color:#5cb85c;border-color:#4cae4c}.btn-success:hover,.btn-success:focus,.btn-success:active,.btn-success.active,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-success{color:#fff;background-color:#47a447;border-color:#398439}.btn-success:active,.btn-success.active,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-success{background-image:none}.btn-success.disabled,.btn-success[disabled],fieldset[disabled] .btn-success,.btn-success.disabled:hover,.btn-success[disabled]:hover,fieldset[disabled] .btn-success:hover,.btn-success.disabled:focus,.btn-success[disabled]:focus,fieldset[disabled] .btn-success:focus,.btn-success.disabled:active,.btn-success[disabled]:active,fieldset[disabled] .btn-success:active,.btn-success.disabled.active,.btn-success[disabled].active,fieldset[disabled] .btn-success.active{background-color:#5cb85c;border-color:#4cae4c}.btn-success .badge{color:#5cb85c;background-color:#fff}.btn-info{color:#fff;background-color:#5bc0de;border-color:#46b8da}.btn-info:hover,.btn-info:focus,.btn-info:active,.btn-info.active,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-info{color:#fff;background-color:#39b3d7;border-color:#269abc}.btn-info:active,.btn-info.active,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-info{background-image:none}.btn-info.disabled,.btn-info[disabled],fieldset[disabled] .btn-info,.btn-info.disabled:hover,.btn-info[disabled]:hover,fieldset[disabled] .btn-info:hover,.btn-info.disabled:focus,.btn-info[disabled]:focus,fieldset[disabled] .btn-info:focus,.btn-info.disabled:active,.btn-info[disabled]:active,fieldset[disabled] .btn-info:active,.btn-info.disabled.active,.btn-info[disabled].active,fieldset[disabled] .btn-info.active{background-color:#5bc0de;border-color:#46b8da}.btn-info .badge{color:#5bc0de;background-color:#fff}.btn-link{font-weight:normal;color:#428bca;cursor:pointer;border-radius:0}.btn-link,.btn-link:active,.btn-link[disabled],fieldset[disabled] .btn-link{background-color:transparent;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none}.btn-link,.btn-link:hover,.btn-link:focus,.btn-link:active{border-color:transparent}.btn-link:hover,.btn-link:focus{color:#2a6496;text-decoration:underline;background-color:transparent}.btn-link[disabled]:hover,fieldset[disabled] .btn-link:hover,.btn-link[disabled]:focus,fieldset[disabled] .btn-link:focus{color:#999;text-decoration:none}
```

Comment: The disabling of the anchor will come from the js in your site, possibly to do with the `class="dropdown-toggle"`! not the CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use "onclick" and "window.open" to solve this.

ex.:

```
<li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" onclick="window.open('iaas/index.html', '_top');" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">IaaS<span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.dropdown a.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
        location.href = this.href;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamed! This worked but I chose Fábio's answer as the solution because it didn't require modifying the js file.

Comment: @etho201 > from where I see it choosing inline javascript over a non-obstrusive version is a bad idea, I would have chosen this one instead...